# How to center align the below subfigure when it stands alone?

Tags: align, subfloats, minipage, subcaption

I have three subfigures as shown in the MWE below, I want to align the subfigure `c` in the center below the two upper figures, how to do that?

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{floatrow}   
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx,xcolor} 
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}

\newcommand{\fakeimage}{{\fboxsep=-\fboxrule\fbox{\rule{0pt}{3cm}\hspace{4cm}}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{mdframed}[
  align=center,
  linecolor=black,
  fontcolor=black,
  backgroundcolor=white,
  userdefinedwidth=0.9\textwidth,
  roundcorner=5pt,
  skipabove=0pt,
  skipbelow=0pt,
  leftmargin=0pt,
  innerleftmargin=20pt,
  innerrightmargin=0pt,
  innertopmargin=5pt,
  innerbottommargin=5pt, 
  innerlinewidth=0pt,
  middlelinewidth=0pt,
  outerlinewidth=1pt]
\floatsetup[subfigure]{captionskip=10pt}
%===================== the two upper subfigures ================
\begin{minipage}{.44\textwidth}
    \begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
    \centering
    \fakeimage
    \caption{Image}\label{fig:image1}
    \end{subfigure}\\[0ex] %
    \qquad
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{.44\textwidth}
    \begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
    \centering
    \fakeimage
    \caption{Image}\label{fig:image12}
   \end{subfigure}
\end{minipage}%
\vfill
%===================== the one below subfigure ================
\begin{minipage}[c]{.94\textwidth}
  \centering
  \begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
  \fakeimage
  \caption{Image}\label{fig:image3}
  \end{subfigure} 
\end{minipage}%
\end{mdframed}
\RawCaption{\caption{General caption}
\label{fig:images}}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

which results in:
[image]

Comment: Have you tried putting `\centering` *before* the `minipage`?

Comment: Yes, but in vain!

Comment: and inside the subfigure?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wouldn't be using `minipage` at all; just `subfigure` is enough.

## Code

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{floatrow}   
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx,xcolor} 
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}

\newcommand{\fakeimage}{{\fboxsep=-\fboxrule\fbox{\rule{0pt}{3cm}\hspace{4cm}}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{mdframed}[
  align=center,
  linecolor=black,
  fontcolor=black,
  backgroundcolor=white,
  userdefinedwidth=0.9\textwidth,
  roundcorner=5pt,
  skipabove=0pt,
  skipbelow=0pt,
  leftmargin=0pt,
  innerleftmargin=20pt,
  innerrightmargin=0pt,
  innertopmargin=5pt,
  innerbottommargin=5pt, 
  innerlinewidth=0pt,
  middlelinewidth=0pt,
  outerlinewidth=1pt]
\floatsetup[subfigure]{captionskip=10pt}
%===================== the two upper subfigures ================
% \begin{minipage}{.44\textwidth}
    \begin{subfigure}{.44\linewidth}
    \centering
    \fakeimage
    \caption{Image}\label{fig:image1}
    \end{subfigure} %
    \qquad
% \end{minipage}
% \begin{minipage}{.44\textwidth}
    \begin{subfigure}{.44\linewidth}
    \centering
    \fakeimage
    \caption{Image}\label{fig:image12}
   \end{subfigure}
% \end{minipage}%
% \vfill
\\[2ex]
%===================== the one below subfigure ================
% \begin{minipage}[c]{.94\textwidth}
% \centering
  \begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
  \centering
  \fakeimage
  \caption{Image}\label{fig:image3}
  \end{subfigure} 
% \end{minipage}%
\end{mdframed}
\RawCaption{\caption{General caption}
\label{fig:images}}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

## Output

[image]

Comment: There's no need for two centering, one inside the subfigure should already be enough

Comment: @dcmst: Ah, missed that one. Thanks for the catch!

Answer (score 0):

You probably already have thought of this but i would just use tikzeditor? Its supereasy to draw stuff there and you can get everything aligned in any way you want.

Comment: thanks for referring to the `tikzeditor`, I must try it.